# Solving a circle equation using tangent property

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

Let $P$ be the point in $XY$ plane and $P'$ is a point such that $OP.OP'=r^2$, where $O,P,P'$ are collinear and $O$ divides $P$ and $P'$ externally and $O$ is the origin.

If the point $P$ lies on the line $x+y=1$, then $P'$ traces

(A) A straight line of slope $\frac{1}{r}$

(B) A circle of radius $\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}$

(C) A circle of radius $\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{2}}$

(D) A circle of radius $\frac{r^2}{2}$

I used the following approach
[image]

If a tangent and secant segment are drawn to a circle from a exterior point then the square of the measure of the secant segment and its external secant segment are illustrated as

$UV^2=UX.UY$

Same concept if applied here where $P$ and $P'$ are collinear with the orgin.

Suppose the locus of P is a straight line $x+y=1$ and let the required circle be $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$

$c=r^2$ by property not able to proceed as we we need to trace locus of $P'$.

But we know that $(h+g)^2+(k+f)^2=(\frac{-g-f-1}{\sqrt{2}})^2$

Comment: It's well known that the image of a line under circular inversion is a circle passing through the origin, it's theorem 1.C here: https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~olga/mat360-spr11/Inversions.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Answer (C). Here is why.

Your question deals with transformation called (geometrical) *inversion* (more precisely inversion with pole $0$ and power $r$) but we do not assume knowledge of it in the solution below. See figure at the bottom.

Let us work with [polar equations](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Rio_Hondo/Math_175%3A_Plane_Trigonometry/06%3A_The_Polar_System/6.02%3A_Graphing_Basic_Polar_Equations) :

If $\vec{OM}=\binom{x}{y}=\rho \binom{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}$, plugging $x=\rho \cos \theta, y=\rho \sin \theta$ into the equation of straight line $x+y=1$ gives its polar equation

$$\rho = \rho_1=\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)}$$

Therefore, the polar equation of the image of this line by the inversion is such that $\rho_1\rho_2=r^2$, giving :

$$\rho = \rho_2=\frac{r^2}{\rho_1}=r^2(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))=r^2 \sqrt{2}\cos(\pi/4-\theta)\tag{1}$$

which is the polar equation of a circle passing through the origin with diameter $r^2 \sqrt{2}$, i.e., with radius $\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{2}}.$

[image]

*Fig. 1 : Case $r=2$. The image of point $A$ on the (blue) straight line is point $A'$ on the (red) circle. The dotted circle is the set of invariant points, i.e., points that are unchanged by the transformation. I have positionned a generic point $M$ with polar angle $\theta$ in order to understand through an easy computation in right triangle with leg $OM$ how equation (1) can be retrieved.*

Comment: I just added a figure done with Geogebra (which can directly deal with inversion under the term "reflection wrt a circle", the invariant circle).

Comment: Any comment ?...